# How to compare two lists and set value to list property

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists

```
    List A                         List B
    ID  FirstName  DepartmentID    ID  FirstName  DepartmentID
    5   Peter      Null            5   Peter      1 
    9   Steve      Null            9   Steve      2
    16  Mark       Null            16  Mark       3
```

I want to compare these lists using LINQ and if IDs from both lists are equal, I want to set DepartmentID in the first list, A list.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What should happen if some but not all items are equal? What if they are equal but in a different order?

Comment: Dont use LINQ for mutation. Just query. But dont produce side effects.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to set if the ID's are equal? You want to set the DepartmentID in the first list to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join them. Then enumerate the results and save the changes:

```
var results = from a in ListA
              join b in ListB on ai.ID equals bi.ID
              select new
              {
                  itemA = a,
                  itemB = b
              };

foreach(var result in results)
{
    // This was not listed as a requirement, but it may be a valid check
    if (itemA.FirstName == itemB.FirstName)
    {
        itemB.DepartmentID = itemA.DepartmentID;
    }
}

DataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ListA.ForEach(a=>a.DepartmentID = ListB.Any(b=>b.ID == a.ID) ? ListB.First(b=>b.ID == a.ID).DepartmentID : null);
```

Edit: if you want to check for null.

Answer (score 1):

```
ListA.Join(ListB, x => x.ID, y => y.ID, (x, y) =>
{
    x.DepartmentID = y.DepartmentID;
    return 0;
}).ToArray();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do use another list and use following code

```
var temp = from ai in ListA 
        join bi in ListB on ai.id equals bi.id
        select bi;

var ListC = temp.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var replacements = ListA
    .Where(a => a.DepartmentID == null)
    .Join(ListB, 
         a => a.ID, 
         b => b.ID, 
         (a, b) => new { Source = a, Replacement = b }
    );

foreach (var item in replacements)
{
    // here you could perform more replacements
    item.Source.DepartmentID = item.Replacement.DepartmentID;
}
```